# How to pass optimization flags to bazel build for tensorflow

Tags: android, c++, makefile, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build TF for android with bazel.
I noticed that when I build TF with makefile c++ code is optimized and it almost 2 times faster than the bazel produced library. What can be the reason of this?
Here the modified tf_copts()

```
def tf_copts():
  return ([
           "-Wno-sign-compare",
           "-fno-exceptions",
           ] +
          if_cuda(["-DGOOGLE_CUDA=1"]) +
          if_android_arm(["-mfpu=neon", "-mfloat-abi=softfp"]) +
          if_x86(["-msse4.1"]) +
          select({
              "//tensorflow:android": [
                  "-DNDEBUG",
                  "-std=c++11",
                  "-DTF_LEAN_BINARY",
                  "-O2",
                  "-fno-rtti",
                  "-DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI",
                  "-DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER",
                  "-fPIE",
                  "-finline-functions",
                  "-funswitch-loops",
                  "-fpredictive-commoning",
                  "-fgcse-after-reload",
                  "-ftree-loop-distribute-patterns",
                  "-fvect-cost-model",
                  "-ftree-partial-pre",
                  "-fpeel-loops"
              ],
              "//tensorflow:darwin": [],
              "//tensorflow:windows": [
                "/DLANG_CXX11",
                "/D__VERSION__=\\\"MSVC\\\"",
                "/DPLATFORM_WINDOWS",
                "/DEIGEN_HAS_C99_MATH",
                "/DTENSORFLOW_USE_EIGEN_THREADPOOL",
              ],
              "//tensorflow:ios": ["-std=c++11"],
              "//conditions:default": ["-pthread"]}))
```

And here is the build command that I use.

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so    --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool    
--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

Also c++ flag section in makefile:

```
    CXXFLAGS +=\
--sysroot $(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(ANDROID_API_VERSION)/arch-$(sysroot_arch) \
-Wno-narrowing \
-fPIE \
-DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI \
-DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER \
-DTF_LEAN_BINARY \
-O2 \
-finline-functions \
-funswitch-loops \
-fpredictive-commoning \
-fgcse-after-reload \
-ftree-loop-distribute-patterns \
-fvect-cost-model \
-ftree-partial-pre \
-fpeel-loops \
-mfloat-abi=softfp \
-mfpu=neon \
-march=armv7-a
```

Comment: Do you see the same performance with the prebuilt (by bazel) APK? https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/out/tensorflow_demo.apk

Note that the APK contains arm64 libs, so we'd need to know if your device is using those before making any conclusions.

What version of bazel and the Android NDK are you using?

Comment: @AndrewHarp Hi, thanks for the comment. NDK version is 12, tensorflow version is 0.12, bazel version is 0.4.5-homebrew. I am building .so library only for arm-v7a with both bazel and makefile. And makefile result is ~2 times faster.

Comment: @AndrewHarp I've updated my question you can see what flags I use in the makefile.

Comment: What device is this, what graph, and what are the actual timings? Can you try the pre-built APK linked above and tell me how that runs for you?

Comment: @AndrewHarp Device is Xioami redmi note 3. Graph is a custom model based on inception. With makefile I c++ code timing was about ~3.2s, with bazel it's 6-7s. I checked apk that you provided, TF Classify works in ~0.5 seconds, TF Stylize for 256x256 works in ~0.9s.