# How to improve computational time in tensorflow

Tags: android, optimization, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow in android. I installed the apk for TFClassify available. I ran the application and it is running swiftly with inference time of not more than 400ms. However when I replaced the available trained model with my model, it is taking around 2000ms for computational before displaying the result. Why is there such a difference and how can I optimize my retrained_graph.pb?

Comment: try using Tensorflow Lite. It's more suitable for mobile devices. Keep in mind that you need first to convert your model to a (.tflite) model so it will be supported by the Lite version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert the retrained model to optimized & quantized graph ?

If not try:

```
 tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
         --input=retrained_graph.pb \
         --output=optimized_graph.pb \
         --input_names=Mul \
         --output_names=final_result

 tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph \
         --input=optimized_graph.pb \
         --output=rounded_graph.pb \
         --output_node_names=final_result \
         --mode=weights_rounded
```

FYI, you have to build these tools first.

Comment: I optimized & quantized the graph and it improved the inference time by few ms. Now inference time is reduced to 1800ms, but still it is very much more than that of the original model(400ms). Any more ways to improve? The size of my model is 87.1 MB

Comment: First, graph file size does not matter. quantized graph can be compressed to ~ 25MB when packed in .APK.  Second, I also want to know how to improve inference performance on Android. 

I didn't tried yet, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585773/how-to-pass-optimization-flags-to-bazel-build-for-tensorflow (build with makefile) is the only clue I could find so far.